# How to make visible editor logo icon as a preview in files with "default open program" set up to Atom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, atom-editor

For example:

When i set default opening program for 'hello.js' file on Visual Studio, Windows show me preview icon like this:

[image]

when i change program on default windows notepad, i see:

[image]

so in preview are displaying dedicated icons for particular programs.

But when i set up Atom Editor as usually file opening program- the icon is not displaying- any logo, or something else (instead of this- windows displays default icon for unrecognized files:

[image]

Is some way to set icons with Atom prettier?

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can right click on the file, click Properties and then select the Customize tab. Click on "Change Icon", browse for Atom.exe and use the icon within it.